# How do I format CSS so that it loads properly?

Tags: css, magento

Using Chrome DevTools, I found the section of CSS I need to modify.  I want to change the color element.

Existing code found with "Inspect" feature of Chrome DevTools

```
#header-phone span:nth-child(1) {
color: #0188cc;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: -10px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

My Magento theme has an option for custom CSS.  How can I add this element to that option to make a CSS change?

I've tried adding this but it does not work.

```
.header-phone .span {color:#6F9C40;}
```

Comment: `.header-phone` should be `#header-phone`, but even with that change you will need to make sure your rule is as, or more, specific than the Magento rule.

Comment: Or vice-versa, depending on your HTML, which is not included in the question...

Comment: `.span` should be `span`.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is not the same as the original.

`#header-phone span:nth-child(1)` vs `.header-phone .span`

`#` is an ID identifier and `.` is a class identifier. You have swapped `#` for `.` and added `.` to `span`.

The original selector targets a `<span>` that is a first child element that exists inside and element with the ID `#header-phone`.

Your selector targets an element with a class of `.span` that exists inside and element with the class `.header-phone`.

Change it to what the actual original selector was or use `#header-phone span` if you want to target ALL `<span>` inside of and element with the ID of `#header-phone`.

*Note:* I'm not sure if leaving off `nth-child(1)` was deliberate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#header-phone span:nth-child(1) {color:#6F9C40;}
```

Comment: This at least shows up in the DevTools, but still does not work.  I see the change, but there is a strikethrough over the line of CSS.  Screenshot:  https://i.imgur.com/WDMKyI9.png

Comment: It is because you have you have mentioned same property in common.css, which is loading after your settings_default.css. Since that file is loading later it has the highest priority and overrides the code in the file settings_default.css. So, either you can remove that code from common.css or call it after settings_default.css from your xml file. I'd suggest you to remove the code from common.css.